# Storing data in local storage through service taking time

Tags: angular, service, local-storage

I am new in angular and trying few things,

Below is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class  StorageService {

  constructor() { }

    get loginUniqueKey(): string {
      return localStorage.getItem('loginUniqueKey')
    }
    set loginUniqueKey(value: string) {
      localStorage.setItem('loginUniqueKey',value)
    }
}
```

And storing following way

```
this.storageService.loginUniqueKey = res.id;
        this.router.navigate(['/nextpage']);
```

It moves to page but on nextpage ngOnInit the local storage value is not available, When I do refresh then its ok.

Another case when I do

```
this.storageService.loginUniqueKey = res.id;
console.log(this.storageService.loginUniqueKey) // just an extra line
        this.router.navigate(['/nextpage']);
```

Then its Ok,

Its look like storing in local storage is taking time

However its Ok when I directly store data in local storage like

```
localStorage.setItem('loginUniqueKey',res.id)
```

How can I make that service working.

Thanks

Comment: In what module do you "provider" your service?. Remember that it must be declared in the most "top" module that shared your components, else Angular understand that there are two differents services

Comment: this is like below  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder,FormArray,FormGroup,Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { StorageService} from '../../common/storage.service';

Comment: Not import in Component, use Module and import in module (don't forget using in provider)  https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules or inject your services in root (new in Angular 6) https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services

Comment: Sorry I am new so not getting exact term, do you mean  constructor(
    private formBuilder:FormBuilder, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private router:Router, 
   private storageService: StorageService
    )

Answer (score 0):

Your app.module must be like

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {StorageService} from './services/storege.service.ts' //<--or whatever

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,
                 ...your modules here... 
  ],
  providers:    [ storageService,
                  ..other services common to all the app..], //<--add yours service here
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  exports:      [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: providers: [StorageService,
    {
      provide: AuthServiceConfig,
      useFactory: provideConfig,
    }]

Comment: My question was about if the ONLY module you have declared as provider your service StorageService was the app.module. If it's true, I don't know what happen, sorry